# Can't move/snap libreoffice window to occupy left or right half

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, libreoffice, snap-windows

The shortcut-keys <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> work fine in other apps but not with Libreoffice but Libreoffice works fine with <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd>.

I have tried to drag but only works with the same functions as the shortcuts.

My system is Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

will it fix if I upgrade?

Sample at

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjYbM.gif

It's like this problem but instead of nautlius with libreoffice.

Comment: Works fine here with Ubuntu 18.04.03 and LibreOffice 6.3.2.2

Comment: My Libreoffice Versión: 6.0.7.3, could it be the problem?

Comment: I have installed your version from Ubuntu software and I have uninstalled Libreoffice 6.0.7.3. Problem solved. Thanks

Comment: I have added that as an answer. Please be kind enough  to mark it as the accepted answer to enable others with the same or similar issue to easily find a solution. Thank you.

Comment: I did this with the graphical interface without write any command. Thank you

Comment: I've amended my answer to reflect that the USC now installs 6.3 - Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shortcut keys work fine, without problem and as expected with Ubuntu 18.04.03 and LibreOffice 6.3.2.2 combination.

Uninstall 6.0.7.3 and/or replace it with 6.3.2.2

This can be achieved either as follows:

Install LibreOffice from the Ubuntu Software Center or

Open a new terminal window <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd>

Add the LibreOffice Fresh PPA :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
```

Run this command to update the list of packages available to install on your system:

```
sudo apt update
```

Finally, run this command to upgrade or install LibreOffice 6.0:

```
sudo apt install libreoffice
```

Thereafter, LibreOffice will be updated to the latest version.